# How to Add a free bootstrap template to an angular 4 cli app?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-cli

I'm new to Angular, my question is, I have created an Angular 4 application with the help of Angular CLI. When I tried to integrate a free bootstrap template from [AdminLTE](https://adminlte.io/), I see the JS and CSS files used in the template. I even tried to add the scripts and styles in `angularcli.json` but its not working as expected. I just need the layout of the theme. Please let me know where to add these JS and CSS files.

Comment: you know it `angular-cli.json`. if its not working show the error log or what you tried.

Comment: Did you install it via npm or did you manually download the source code and add it to your project ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what this theme is supposed to achieve, that you couldn't do with Bootstrap yourself, still, reading up on it I gathered the following:

While in your project directory you can install this theme with `npm install admin-lte --save` 
Implementing it is still up to you though, and a good place to start is [their layout page](https://adminlte.io/docs/2.4/layout).